# get the text inside a zipped text file without extraction

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, zip

I want to get the content of the `file1.txt` of my `archive.zip` without extrancting the file.
For all these commands I obtain `caution: filename not matched:  file1.txt`

`unzip -p ~/archive.zip ~/archive.zip/file1.txt | less`
`unzip -p ~/archive.zip ~/archive/file1.txt | less`
`unzip -p ~/archive.zip file1.txt | less`

the `archive.zip` is at the home directory, and the respective names are correct.
Hardcoding the path, produces the same undesired outcome:

`unzip -p /home/pi/archive.zip ~/archive.zip/file1.txt | less`
`unzip -p /home/pi/archive.zip ~/archive/file1.txt | less`
`unzip -p /home/pi/archive.zip file1.txt | less`

I am trying to do this in a raspberry-pi.
The expected output is the content of the file1.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the zip extracts into a directory and the file is present there, eg `file.zip` creates a `someproject-name` top level directory and the contents are under that. So you can do something like this:

`unzip -p /home/pi/archive.zip '*/file1.txt'` So it would look at the top level directory aswell due to the glob.

Comment: what do you mean by "the glob"?

Comment: the globstar, `*` means "match everything".  If you have a file in a path like`./dir/path/file.txt`, `./dir/*/file.txt` will match every directory under `dir` which includes `path` aswell.